# Unable to upload files over 30MB

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, iis-7, amazon-ec2, iis-6

I recently moved a .NET webforms site from an old IIS 6 over to IIS 7 and am now unable to upload file larger than 30MB.

All the web files are the same and so is the web.config:

```
<httpRuntime
          executionTimeout="36000"
          maxRequestLength="1024000"
          useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"
          minFreeThreads="8"
          minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4"
          appRequestQueueLimit="100" />
```

**Additional info:**

IIS 6 server was running on a physical dedicated machine. IIS 7 is running on AWS EC2, with much more memory (but I'm not using S3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something changed in IIS 7 onwards for this limit value..  (don't ask why!)
here is the new config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- this is in bytes (100 MB), not KB unlike maxRequestLength -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```